# How to send a file through email SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a string and couple of other variables as an outcome of coding with GUI. I saved them in a file. What I want to do is get email address of recipient through a string and send the file automatically on that id. Want to do it through a function. Can anyone provide the code or provide guidance for it?

I'm using SFML library

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=15558.0) could help? Google is your best friend ;)

Comment: Did it a lot. But the friend wasnt able to help too